# Data scraping from web for custom pages UiPath RPA

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-activity

I am scraping from web (A book website), so looking for a dynamic way to extract the data from page 5 to 7, I don't know how many pages my search will have every time. It will be difficult to count the whole data. I am trying to extract from each page wise, what if the search don't have page 7 and only 6 pages then I can add an error handle which tells me there are only 6 pages available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think simple.

1. Select whole table.
2. Delete first 100 (**I expect 20 entries per page**) rows.
3. Done.

[image]

### Alternativly

Start the web table via URL Parameter. For example in Google:

https://www.google.com/search?q=uipath&start=50

Comment: But then add this to your question :). I think I solved your question completely. If not edit your question. Otherwise yes, maybe my tips helping you.

Comment: I used "navigate to" activity to start from page 5 and inside a while loop I had a if else statement. If 5 to 7 pages exists do the data scraping else send a message with the counter of page number "Do data found on Page 7". It worked!

Comment: Great good job. So in case it helped you, feel free to accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Dont use datascrabing auto next page feature, check next page button with element exist, and use if statement for nextpage element exist counter,

example if (nextpage not exist)then if (counter < 7) send error or alert mail